# Prove that: $2a^2+3bc+4\ge b^2+c^2+5a$

Tags: inequality, cyclic-decomposition

> For $a,b,c\ge 0;a^2b+b^2c+c^2a=1;a=\max\{a,b,c\}.$  Prove that: $$2a^2+3bc+4\ge b^2+c^2+5a$$

*I try to prove this inequality in the following way:*

1. If $4-5a\ge 0 \rightarrow qed.$
2. If $4-5a<0 \rightarrow a>\dfrac{4}{5}.$
   Let $$f(a)=2a^2+3bc+4-b^2-c^2-5a$$
   $$f'(a)=4a-5<0$$
   So we only prove this inequality for $a=a_{\min}.$

Okay, now notice that the equality holds when $a=1,b=1,c=0$ or $a=1,b=0,c=1.$ I try
$$1=a^2b+b^2c+c^2a\le a^2\left(b+c\right)+c^2a \Rightarrow a \ge {\frac {\sqrt {c^4+4b+4c}-{c}^{2}}{2\left(b+c\right)}},$$
which implies one of the value of $a_{\min}.$ But now, the inequality seems be harder since the sqrt sign appears, and I stuck here.

Helps me!

Comment: nice ! Where did you get this inequality?

Comment: I get it in facebook.

Comment: You can't assume $a\geq b\geq c$ because the constraint $a^2b+b^2c+c^2a=1$ does not allow you to swap $b$ and $c$.  However, since the desired inequality is symmetric in $b,c$, you can get away with it if you symmetrise the constraint.

Comment: @user10354138 Hmm, I see, do you have any other idea to work with $a^2b+b^2c+c^2a=1?$

Comment: @user10354138 I have edited.

Comment: @tthnew There is a computer solution but it is complicated.

Comment: @RiverLi What's the idea?

Comment: @tthnew Ugly. First $2a^2+3bc+4Q^{2/3}\ge b^2+c^2+5aQ^{1/3}$ where $Q = a^2b+b^2c+c^2a$. Second, after some manipulation, we remove the root sign to get a polynomial. Then we use BW.

Comment: @RiverLi But here is $a=\max\{a,b,c\},$ not $a=\min\{a,b,c\}$ so can't use $c=a+u,b=a+v.$ Is there any other substitution, which works for this inequality?

Comment: @tthnew By BW, you can let $b = \frac{a}{1+s}, c = \frac{a}{1+t}$ for $s, t \ge 0$. There are quite a few substitutions rather than $c =  a + u, b = a+v$ used in BW.